# ruby activerecord relation collection search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In order to speed up my code which is currently running way too many DB queries in a loop (`bar = find_or_create_by()....`) in order to create a join entry with such things as `foo.bar_id = bar.id` I figured I'd store all the `bars` in memory with one `Bar.all` load before the loop. The question is how do I quickly search in all these `bars` for a specific `bar.name` ? I tried `bar.where(name: ...)` but that goes back to the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, to speed up the things, you can get all the bars, and put them in the memory, in a hash that maps each (bar.name) to an array of bars.

for example:

```
bars_hash = Bar.all.group_by(&:name)
```

Then,

```
bars_hash[name]
```

will return all the bars that match the name, or `nil` if none.
With this, you will avoid doing a sequential search for each `Foo`.

But if you have I hope your memory won't fill up if you have too many `Bar`s

Comment: Thanks, your way is much faster since it is key based. the subsequent searches from the other answer make it slow due to large number of `bars`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is:

```
bars.select { |bar| bar.name == 'the name I want' }
```

This uses `Enumerable`'s `select` API to select elements from a collection which match a query.